# Funny unsigned in java

Tags: java

I found the unsigned integer is so straight in Java. If I want to present the 0xFXXX XXXX, Java requires me to declare a long variable to store the 0xFXXX XXXX, and do a bitwise AND operation with the 4294967295(0xFFFFFFFFL).
Any one could share your experiences about the unsigned problem to others or me?

Comment: Java doesn't have unsigned types, you need to account for those yourself. if you're assuming unsigned-ness, then, well, don't. As a helper, Google does provide convenience methods for bit operations in their public domain Guava library (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), check the classes SignedBytes and UnsignedBytes.

Comment: It is too funny - may javac does allow int unsigned = 0xfeefabba; it doesn't require to declare a long variable.

Comment: Thanks for your shared Esko, guava-libraries is awesome~

Comment: @Ingo -- are you sure your variable name in this case isn't 'unsigned'? :)

Comment: The name is "unsigned" and what it names is in fact neither unsigned nor signed - this depends entirely on how it is used.

Comment: i uses the unsigned when display it on UI. like -1 is display as 4294967295. In face, the value is just a value. in detail, i don't care about what it should be. But on UI side, I need to use Long.toString and Long.parseLong to transform then from value to string.

Comment: I have fix them before I post this question. As my subject, it is just fun. And different than what I have used ever.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check this out: http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml

C++:

```
unsigned byte b = ...;
b += 100;

unsigned int v = ...;
v *= 2;
```

Java equivalent:

```
int b = ...;
b = (b + 100) & 0xff;

long v = ...;
v = (v * 2) & 0xffffffffL;
```

When you come to using the unsigned value, cast it to the type you want, and it will wrap naturally, giving you the correct value:

```
// Example: write an unsigned int (stored in a long)
// to a byte buffer.
ByteBuffer bb = ...
long unsignedInt = ...
bb.putInt((int) unsignedInt);
```

Comment: This snippet has a problem at these statement,
long v = ...;
v = (v * 2) & 0xffffffff;

the 'v' should always equal to -1. We must use '& 0xffffffffL'.

Answer (score 0):

In java `int`egers are 32 bits long; however, the first bit is for sign. In effect, integers are only 31 bits long.

Your number is positive 32 bit long digit; therefore, it cannot fit into `int`eger, thus need a `long`.

EDIT: Why the downvote?!

Integers are represented as 2's complement, for simple 8 bit word:

```
MSB 
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   =   127
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   =   126
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   =   2
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   =   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   =   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   =   −1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   =   −2
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   =   −127
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   =   −128
```

MSB, the first digit effectively indicates the sign

**Edit 2**: I am tired of discussing a moot point. Before downvoting, refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit)

Comment: This is not so. You can hold a 32 bit unsigned int in a 32 bit signed int. Whether it is signed or not is only relevant in certain operations (relational comes to mind) and on output. Yet, addition for example, works the same, no matter what. This is the good thing about 2s complement.

Comment: It is relevant in a lot of operations. And addition works only until you add int to long.

Comment: @Ingo: Run this piece of code: `{ int x = 2147483647; System.out.println(x + 1); x++; System.out.println(x); }`

Comment: @CMR - so what? You seem to confuse external and internal representation. I said that one must take care on output, in general, in every conversion.

Comment: @Ingo, sorry, I _am_ confused. Wasn't this question about Java?

Comment: @Vladimir: You mean, if I have a large unsigned number in the int, that would be interpreted as negative in signed mode? This is true, because the int is sign extended before being added to the long. This must of course be taken into account when working with unsigend int in Java. Nevertheless, every int can represent values 0 .. 2^32-1 if one so desires.

Comment: @CMR - Sure, about representation of integers in Java, to be exact. And there the JLS tells us that they will use a 32bit word in 2's complement format. And every old programmer knows very well that one can interpret every N-bit quantity as one pleases, signed or unsigned. Of course, one must take the semantics of the operations into account, and in the Java case the semantics are signed, up to the >>> operator. Sometimes it makes no difference, sometimes it matters, it's a question of knowledge, ye know.

Comment: @Ingo, your comment is missleading in the sense that "the first bit is the sign" may be easily confused by "sign & value" instead of 2 complement and they are completely different.

Comment: Yes I think to hold the value is not a problem. This is a habit for me, I use C/CPP before. And at this point, that is very very different.

Comment: @SJuan76 - now I am really confused. To my knowledge, I did nowhere state such a falsehood as "the first bit is the sign". I am the one who tries to make clear, that 32 bits of data are just that - 32 bits of data, no more, no less. It's the operations on that data that may **treat** the first bit as sign. Actually, still many really don't, this is the trick with 2s complement that you can add, for example, 2 equally sized words **without** caring about signs. But of course, there **are** operations that do interpret the sign - like conversion of int to strings, etc.

Comment: @Ingo, the original question, verbatim: _Java requires me to declare a long variable to store the 0xFXXX XXXX_. You say, I quote, "_And every old programmer knows very well that one can interpret every N-bit quantity as one pleases, signed or unsigned_." I guess I am extremely dumb, as I cannot understand the relation between the two.

Comment: If I comment on your text, then I mean what you wrote, e.g. "the first bit is the sign", "an int has really only 31 bit" (which is, btw, absolute nonsense), "therefore, a 32 unsigned int can't fit an an int" (also nonsense). That java **requires** a long to store 0xffffffff is just plain **WRONG**.

Comment: Agreed. It isn't the sign, really. The first bit counts for -(the maximum range) or such if set. All the other bits count for +(their normal value in the bit sequence), as expected. It's just a VERY weighty value :) As far as I know. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Chris - the truth is, it's just a bit like the orhers. The java language provides many operations that lead us to believe that bit was per se something magical like a sign bit or so. This treatment of a 32 bit quantity as signed 2s complement integer number is **the** standard interpretation in primitive operations as well as in libraries in java. Nevertheless, one could write a program in java that treats the bits in reverse order, or as a rational number with a certain number of bits interpreted as nominator and another number of bits used as denominator (not very useful, btw, but possible)

Comment: @Ingo, the rule of thumb: For an n-bit integer, signed values are -(2**(n-1))..2**(n-1)-1, and unsigned range 0..2**n-1. The full n bits cannot be used, as a bit needs to be used for sign. Whether it is 1's complement, 2's complement, Excess-n, sign&magnitude et.c, et.c.,

Comment: @CMR - you don't get it, do you? In 2s complement, the MSB **indicates** the sign of the number, but it **isn't** the sign. If it were, what number would be 0x80000000? -0 perhaps? No, it's that simple: we have 2^32 different bit patterns, and we can assign each pattern a different number. Certain assignments like "2s complement" stand out insofar as they have nice properties, such as that the MSB indicates the sign, or that it does not matter whether we interpret 0xfffffffe + 0x00000001 as ((2^32-2)+1) mod 2^32 or ((-2)+1) mod 2^32 - we get the correct result for both with the same operation.

Comment: @Ingo, I do understand your viewpoint. However, my point is 32 bits are not enough to hold his 0xf0000000 in Java, as a bit is used for sign. Hence, he needs a long. And, yes, 0x80000000 is -0 in [sign&mag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method) You talked about internal and external representation, but are ignoring the simple point of why so.

Comment: @CMR The Wiki article correctly says that the sign bit **indicates** the sign (in a particular interpretation, namely 2s component). It does not state, as you do, that this **IS** the sign. But it looks like nothing can help,  you even go so far as to brush aside the **FACT**, that 0xf000000 can be stored in a java int variable.

Comment: @Ingo, I completely agree, also, I thought I also said _it indicates_? There is no question that `ffffffff` can be stored in int. The minute you type 0xf0000000 in Java, it is considered as 2147483648, which cannot be fitted into an int!

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the most common method of representing signed integers - [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)